# DOT Validetor Using if (eregi

Tags: php, forms, eregi

Is it possible to use a dot `.` checker in a email form, so that if specific field have a dot, then this will tell the user to do not put dot in those field. I have tried with this but don't works:

```
if (eregi('.', $notes)) {
    die ("Do NOT PUT DOT HERE");
}
```

So, any idea what to do?

Comment: `ereg` is deprecated. You should use `preg` instead. Also note, that dots are valid in email addresses ;)

Comment: use  strpos() or strstr() for this, no need for preg

Comment: can you give a example here, how i should use , i ama beginner.. so it would be much better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the manual says:

> Tip: Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

here is the strpos() method:

```
<?php

$findme   = '.';
$pos = strpos($notes, $findme);

if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "Do NOT PUT DOT HERE";
} else {
     //other
}

?>
```

I would not recommend die\exit in most case.

Comment: **you** are welcome. so now tick check the green answer tick next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('~\.~', $notes)) {
  // Do something useful
}
```

Comment: "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster. "

Comment: @Dragon Yeah, sure, late here ;) Currently I'm waiting, that you'll post that as answer (because I face-palmed myself when reading your comment above).